# Custom view layout line overstriking other elements in API 16

Tags: android, android-api-levels

The problem:

[image: 123 strike through]

What I need:

[image: 1-2-3]

Everything works fine on API 23, but in API 16 I get this problem running it in emulator. Android Studio also shows the correct layout on the device screen.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:cardview="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    cardview:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
    cardview:cardElevation="4dp"
    style="@style/AppTheme"
    cardview:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_compra_header_titulo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:text="ETAPA"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_compra_one"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_looks_one_black_24dp"

                android:backgroundTint="@android:color/tab_indicator_text" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view_compra_header_one"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="3dip"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:background="@color/secondaryText"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/iv_compra_one"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/iv_compra_two" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_compra_two"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_looks_two_black_24dp"
                android:backgroundTint="@android:color/tab_indicator_text" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view_compra_header_two"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="3dip"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:background="@color/secondaryText"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/iv_compra_three"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/iv_compra_two" />


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_compra_three"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_looks_3_black_24dp"
                android:backgroundTint="@android:color/tab_indicator_text" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep in mind that Android API level 16 does not support the `start` and `end` attributes as those were introduced in API level 17. Thus those are just ignored.

Just add the equivalent `left` and `right` attributes to make the layout work on API level 16 and below.

Comment: Glad I could help ;)